# open a page via facebox and show particular tab on load

Tags: jquery, show, facebox

i currently have the facebox jquery plugin running on my site and when a user clicks a link it opens a page within the facebox.

within the page that is loaded by default we hide a number of divs via jquery. Links within the page trigger the page to fadeIn the required divs.

My issue is, the caller page has links that are to open the page and display the required divs by default.

what im wondering is...

href="linktopage.html" rel=facebox"

will open the page.

the divs contained within i would like to display if they are required.

Ive seen something similar before

href="linktopage.html#divid" rel="facebox"

the div id is tagged wtithin the URL.

How would one listen for this #divid in the url to display the appropriate div onload ?

any ideas greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you say `href="linktopage.html#divid" rel="facebox"`, Facebox will get "linktopage.html" and process it to show some part, in this case it is "divid". So, your "linktopage.html" can't know which div is called by this way.

However, you can use querystring like `href="linktopage.html?show=divid" rel="facebox"` to send information. Moreover, you can also you add # sign if you want to load some part of your page using `href="linktopage.html?show=divid#divHalaluyaContainer" rel="facebox"`. Then you can get the query string even with using javascript and show necessary div and hide others.